# How to return a list of vertices that have at minimum n edges from an adjacency list in python?

Tags: python, graph

I want to write a function `friend(my_class, n)` that return a list of people who have minimum n friends, return an empty list if no person has at least n friends.
This my code, can someone tell me what i did wrong?

```
my_class = [[1,2,3],[0,3],[0,4],[0,1],[2]]
def friend(my_class,n):
    for j in range(len(my_class)):
        if my_class[j][n] >= n:
            return my_class[j]
    return ([])
```

because when i call:

`friend(my_class, 2)`

it returns `[1,2,3]` instead of `[0,1,2,3]`

Comment: Could you add some input data? It's impossible to test/run your code currently.

Comment: You have a return inside a for loop. This just returns the first match.

Comment: hi, thanks, so i need to write a for loop after if?

Comment: You need [mcve] How do I know if [1, 2, 3] is wrong? I have to take your word, and I don't believe you. But computers don't lie. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @KennyOstrom: hi, thanks, i edited my post and added the picture screenshot when i tried to run it.

Comment: hi, sorry, my input data can be : `my_class = [[1,2,3],[0,3],[0,4],[0,1],[2]]`

Comment: no screenshots. I want to copy your block of code, go to my python window, hit paste, then run it and see the error or incorrect result. Put the input data in the question so this can happen. Thanks.

Comment: @KennyOstrom hi, i added input

Answer (score 0):

This is basic debugging, which you need to learn to do for yourself.

```
my_class = [[1,2,3],[0,3],[0,4],[0,1],[2]]
def friend(my_class,n):
    for j in range(len(my_class)):
        if my_class[j][n] >= n:
            return my_class[j]
    return ([])
```

friend(my_class, 2) will enter a for loop. In the case where j is 0, we look at my_class[0] and there are 3 friends. Because 3>2 we immediately return. Once the function executes a return, it is DONE. It will not continue in the for loop.

You found the adjacency list for the first node which has at least 2 friends, and that's what you returned. I can't go any further without doing your homework for you, but in answer to your question, "What did you do wrong?" you executed return (on the wrong data) before the function was done.

Comment: Consider that if you want to return a list with new data, you have to make one. On another note about your loop, look up enumerate, that might help.